# Autoformat on custom event in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

So currently Visual Studio will autoformat on `;` so for example

```
int a=3
```

becomes

```
int a = 3;
```

but I'd like to autoformat on a custom event, such as when I smartbreak a line. Smartbreaking is by default Shift+Enter, when you break the line so that for example

```
int a = 3;
```

will stay like that even if you smart-linebreak in the middle of the statement.

Do you think this is possible? It enhances workflow significantly since my editor will often automatically add the semicolon at the end. By smartbreaking I will save a bunch of time.

This is the closest I've found:

[image]

Comment: I've (sort of) found a way. Just set Edit.FormatDocument keybind to Shift+something so that  you can quickly press Shift+something+Enter to simulate what I was suggesting.

Comment: [Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d) can perform a Format Document on Save.